# How to add multiple words to one line of command

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to run a function. When you hit the button if the textbox includes the following words below it will display "Please don't swear." The problem is that I'm trying to add multiples words to one line of command using the "or" function.
For some reason it does not work. Here is my code:

```
If InStr(1, Command.Text, "shit" Or "ass", vbTextCompare) Then
            MsgBox("Please don't swear.")
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not in VB6 anymore Toto.  Let's not use `InStr` or `MsgBox`.

```
Dim prohibitedWords = {"bad", "word"}

If prohibitedWords.Any(Function(s) TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1) Then
    '...
End If
```

I used `IndexOf` rather than `Contains` there to allow a case-insensitive comparison.

One issue with that is that is will match parts of other legitimate words.  To avoid that, you should probably use a `Regex` and match whole words only.  I'll leave it to you to search how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything is working fine now! Sorry about the Msgbox, what should I use instead? Messagebox.Show("text")?

Comment: That's correct. You can use all those VB6 holdovers if you want but there's almost always better options.